# backspace key not working in Safari and Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari

I have a rather simple event listener attached to an input field

```
const modifyKey = function(event) {
    const ENTER = 13;
    const BACKSPACE = 8;

    event = event || window.event;
    const charCode = event.which || event.keyCode;

    if (charCode == ENTER) { … }
    else if (charCode == BACKSPACE { … }
}
```

Oddly, the above code works fine in Firefox, but in Safari and Chrome, only the ENTER part works. Nothing happens on BACKSPACE.

What is going on?

Comment: what event are you using? `kepress` does not detect backspace with the exception of firefox. `keyup` and `keydown` will detect backspace.

Comment: gack! that was it. Thanks. Make that an answer and I will vote it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kepress` event does not detect backspace with the exception of firefox which added support for it recently.

`keyup` and `keydown`, however, will detect backspace.